# Swap part of a PHP variable name?

Tags: php, variables, dynamic-variables

Is something like the following pseudocode possible in PHP?

```
$backing_type='work';

$work_token='123';
$review_token='456';   

echo ${$backing_type}_token;

//prints '123';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can do the following:

```
echo ${$backing_type . '_token'};
```

However, I would consider this messy programming.  Using an array would be preferred:

```
$arr = array('work' => 123, 'review' => 456);
echo $arr[$backing_type];
```

Comment: thanks, was having trouble wrapping my head around variable variables